# Passing multiple data through @Requestbody Spring MVC, JSONobject is not getting updated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am facing issue while updating JSON object in loop, I am getting overwritten data in json object.

**JSON Request from UI**

```
{

"attribute":[
{
"name":"Program",
"status":"Active"
},
{
"name":"Software",
"status":"Active"
}
]
}
```

**Java COde**

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray res = new JSONArray();

    int i=1;
for (AttributeList attr_list : addmodel.getAttribute()) {
response.put("name", attr_list.getAttribute_nm());
                    response.put("status", attr_list.getCategory());

                    res.add(response);
                    System.out.println("inloop--res "+res);
                    obj.put(i, res);//issue is here 
                    System.out.println("inloop--obj "+obj);
                    i++;
}
```

**Output**

```
["1": {"name":"Software","status":"Active"}, "2":{"name":"Software","status":"Active"}]
```

Data is getting overwritten in both positions.

Sorry I'm not able to put whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new JSONObject response = new JSONObject(); again in the loop for next value.
**Reason:** Since you are not creating a new object for each value in the list, the previous reference is getting replaced by the new value.

```
JSONObject response = null;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray res = new JSONArray();

    int i=1;
for (AttributeList attr_list : addmodel.getAttribute()) {
response = new JSONObject();
response.put("name", attr_list.getAttribute_nm());
                    response.put("status", attr_list.getCategory());

                    res.add(response);
                    System.out.println("inloop--res "+res);
                    obj.put(i, res);//issue is here 
                    System.out.println("inloop--obj "+obj);
                    i++;
}
```